# Datetime format Convert

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to convert below format in DateTime. I want to convert it to datetime

> "08-22T03:32"

Answer (score 5):

Since you don't have year in your date string, default will be current year, something like this :

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "MM-ddTHH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: If you just leave off the year and use "MM-ddTh:mm" the current year will be assumed.

Comment: Its Return Exception when we try to Convert 24H format Like "08-22T13:32"

Comment: yes, I didn't see it so I update it again ;) it should be uppercase HH

Answer (score 0):

If the string is formatted correctly, **DateTime.Parse()** is what you're looking for. But I think the 'date' part of that string is incomplete for it to work.